# React passing import name as prop on img src passing as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component where I have an image path imported and then it's name passed in the img src, like this:

```
import { Myimage } from './images/image.jpg';

const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <img src={Myimage} alt="" />
  </div>
);
```

The above works fine but I want to pass the name of the import using a prop but it's returning a string so it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <img src={props.myprop} alt="" />
  </div>
);
```

Here is the call:

```
<MyComponent myprop="Myimage" />
```

How can I pass an import name in the img src?

Comment: can you provide the log of props.myprop - you mentioned its returning as a string, i am thinking of formatting the string but not sure what is the value you have there

Comment: Also, how are you passing Myimage as prop? Show us how are you calling your MyComponente component.

Comment: It's returning this: <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" /> after rendering

Comment: Question has been updated with the call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<MyComponent myprop={Myimage} />
```

Comment: Could you please then mark it as resolved so that the question could be closed?

Comment: The question was not posted by me :)